# How to bind CheckBoxes to a bidimensional array in WPF?

Tags: wpf, data-binding

I'm new to WPF, so please be patient with me. I have a bidimensional int array (8x8), a uniform grid (8 rows and 8 columns). In each cell of my grid there is a CheckBox. When I click on a checkbox I wish that the corresponding element in my array to change from "0" to "1". When I uncheck again the CheckBox, I wish that this change be reflected in my array.

Further, I will take each row from in my int[8,8] matrix (for example 10010101 - first checkbox in the uniform grid is checked, the second is not checked and so on), convert it to a decimal number and send it over the serial port when I click a button.

Then I want to change the sending process ( process all  8 rows and send the data) in such way that it takes place every time I click on a checkbox from my grid.

I'm stucked with the Bindings. 
I hope someone can give me an advice on how should I to do this.

This is my XAML code. Somehow I succeeded to make a binding for my first CheckBox but I'm not understanding well why it's working and If I did the best coding.  If I continue in this way I should create a property for every element in my array and I'm sure this is not the right way to do it (because I hardcoded data[0,0]).

```
    <Window x:Class="CheckBox_Matrix_Binding.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="220" Width="200" ResizeMode="NoResize" >
    <Grid x:Name="mainGrid">

        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="4*"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <UniformGrid x:Name="checkBoxGrid" Grid.Row="0" Rows="3" Columns="3" >
            <CheckBox x:Name="ChekBox0" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" IsChecked="{Binding Mode=TwoWay, Path=DataProperty}" />
            <CheckBox x:Name="ChekBox1" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
            <CheckBox x:Name="ChekBox2" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
            <CheckBox x:Name="ChekBox3" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
            <CheckBox x:Name="ChekBox4" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
            <CheckBox x:Name="ChekBox5" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
            <CheckBox x:Name="ChekBox6" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
            <CheckBox x:Name="ChekBox7" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
            <CheckBox x:Name="ChekBox8" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>

        </UniformGrid>
        <Grid Grid.Row="1" x:Name="buttonsGrid">
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <Button x:Name="btnSetTrue"  VerticalAlignment="Center" Grid.Column="0" Content="Set _True" Margin="5" Click="btnSetTrue_Click"  ></Button>
            <Button x:Name="btnSetFalse" VerticalAlignment="Center" Grid.Column="1" Content="Set _False" Margin="5" Click="btnSetFalse_Click"  ></Button>
        </Grid>

    </Grid>

</Window>
```

This is my code behind:

```
using System;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.ComponentModel;

namespace CheckBox_Matrix_Binding
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {

        private DataMatrix _dataMatrix = new DataMatrix() ;
        public bool _DataMatrixProperty
        {
            get { return _dataMatrix.DataProperty; }
            set
            {
                _dataMatrix.DataProperty = value;
            }
        }
        public MainWindow()
        {

            InitializeComponent();
            checkBoxGrid.DataContext = _dataMatrix;                    
        }

        private void ChekBox0_Checked(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void btnSetTrue_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            _dataMatrix.DataProperty = true;
        }

        private void btnSetFalse_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            _dataMatrix.DataProperty = false;
        }        
    }

     //THe class DataMatrix implements INotifyPropertyChanged interface
    public class DataMatrix: INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
       public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
       private bool[,] data;
       public bool DataProperty //this is a property
       {
           get { return data[0, 0]; }
           set { 
                 data[0, 0] = value;
                 OnPropertyChanged("DataProperty");
               }
       }
       public DataMatrix()
       {
           data = new bool[3, 3];
       }

       public void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
       {
           if (PropertyChanged != null)
           {
               PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
           }
       }
    }  
}
```

Should I use another approach? 
Thankyou in advance :)

Comment: What did you tried with the bindings that got you stucked?

Comment: I do not know how to bind every CheckBox with Every element in my Array without writing code for each of them.